# QueryDSL and Operation on MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, querydsl

I like to query a mongoDB over QueryDSL (Springboot application with REST interface). The most works fine, If I put a parameter field more than once and associate with the and operator, the other one is always over written.

Example:

```
numberPath.gt(2).and(numberPath.lt(10))
```

The String from the query dsl looks correct:

> setPoint.value < 10.0 && setPoint.value > 2.0

I log the query to mongoDB:

> DEBUG org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - find using query:  "value" : { "$gt" : 2.0 }

The query for the < 10 was not logged.

Can anybody help me.

Greets Benjamin

Comment: Are there any exceptions when query is executed?

Comment: no nothing...he just override the last query lt(10)